# How to rerender a component which uses observable

Tags: angular

I have some code where I am using observable. Here I am getting the data as expected.

But I wanted to rerender the page by calling the vm$ observer again from `.cs` file.

Can you help with this?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
<app-product-filter-form
  *ngIf="categories$ | async as categories"
  @fadeIn
  [categories]="categories"
  [filters]="vm.filters"
  (filtered)="load.next($event)">
</app-product-filter-form>
 <app-product-table
  class="product-table"
  *ngIf="vm.data.length > 0 && !vm.loading"
  @fadeIn
  [dataSource]="vm.data"
  [pagination]="vm.pagination"
  (paginated)="load.next($event)"
  (saveproduct)="Save($event)"
  >
</app-product-table>
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is with the ChangeDetectionStrategy inside the app-product-filter-form and app-product-table. Could you add in the question more about them?